# Change + character to - in Html::encode decode function of YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change the + character to - in Html encode decode functions of YII2.
How should i change that? Does any one know?

I try to do this changes in BaseHtml helper class of yii2 but not working.

```
public static function encode($content, $doubleEncode = true)
{
    return str_replace("+","-",htmlspecialchars($content, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE, Yii::$app ? Yii::$app->charset : 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode));
}

public static function decode($content)
{

    return htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("-","+",$content), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `encode` method. Also you should not modify any files under `vendor` directory, it will be overriden on the next `composer update` and overall it's very bad practice.

Process this separately using `str_replace` for example:

Minus to plus:

```
str_replace('-', '+', $string);
```

Backwards:

```
str_replace('+', '-', $string);
```

Place it in separate methods or just one method with additional parameter.

**Official docs:**

- [str_replace](http://str_replace('-',%20'+',%20$string);)

Comment: actually i am using Html encode,decode function for encoding and decoding my url and when space is come in my url encode is replacing that space as + sign so that's why i want to replace that + sign to - sign.Thanks for help.